# Get Json Data on JSP Using JSTL from spring model

Tags: json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my spring controller, I have created a json :

```
{
    "productsData": [
        {
            "code": "0100",
            "name": "Shirt",
            "summary": "Shirt for males"
        },
        {
            "code": "0101",
            "name": " Shirt 1",
            "summary": "Shirt for males"
        },
        {
            "code": "0102",
            "name": "Shirt 2",
            "summary": "Shirt for males"
        }
    ]
}
```

And added this json to model attribute as :

```
model.addAttribute("productsJson", responseDetailsJson.toString());
```

When I am getting values from `json` on `jsp` as :

```
<c:if test="${not empty productsJson}">
<c:out value="${productsJson.productsData}"></c:out>
<c:forEach var="product" items="${productsJson.productsData}">
</c:forEach>
```

The exception is :-

> ${productsJson.productsData}' Property 'productsData' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: JSTL `<c:forEach` is used to iterate over java collection. not json data

Answer (score 2):

The error is produced because you are trying to use `productsData` from an String. If you want to use this property you shouldn't use `toString` method in the controller.

Even if you use `productsJson.productsData`, I don't think is the correct way to call it. Most likely you should use `productsJson['productsData']`. This is because `productsJson` is a `Map` not an `Object`